# Unable to get namespace System.Deployment.Application

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

I am trying to get this: System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.IsFirstRun

But the application namespace is not there. I just see System.Deployment.Internal. The object browser, however, shows me all the properties and methods of that namespace, but my app can't see it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you add a reference to System.Deployment?

Comment: No i did not...After adding the reference it worked!
Since i was getting Internal under System.Deployment, i was under the impression i need not add reference to it. Thanks for you help :)